# Form open, if already open just bring to front

Tags: c#

I want to open form in panel if the form already open i want to just bring it front but giving me error.

```
private void SettingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Settings childSetting = new Settings() { TopLevel = false, TopMost = true };
    childSetting.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    panel2.Controls.Add(childSetting);

    FormCollection FC = Application.OpenForms;
    foreach (Form fc in FC)

    {
        if (fc.Text == "Settings")

        {
            childSetting.BringToFront();
        }
        else
        {
            childSetting.Show();
            childSetting.BringToFront();
        }
    }
}
```

`System.InvalidOperationException`: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'

Comment: _Settings current = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Settings>().FirstOrDefault();_ There should be a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: In the above code, you "BringToFront();" all the forms. You need to exit the loop (break), after " childSetting.BringToFront();" for the "Settings" form only.

Comment: It is always a good idea to include the _exception details_, i.e. where the exception occurs. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

This line of code is your issue:

```
FormCollection FC = Application.OpenForms;
```

It's creating the "live" collection of open forms that is, in some way, being modified. You need to change the code to produce a static array of forms.

Try this:

```
Form[] FC = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().ToArray();
```

Comment: i tryed but now open new form every time even open

Comment: What does "now open new form every time even open" mean? And there's nothing in my code that would do that. You need to update your question with a [mcve].